# Vim cannot find medical spell files

Tags: vimrc, netrw, spell-checking, linux, linux-ubuntu

##### Problem specification

I would love to have a medical spell dictionary in `vim`.
Currently, I have a lot of medical terms in my own personal English dictionary right now. However, using an official medical dictionary would be a superior solution.

#### What I tried

So I tried adding the following to my `vimrc`:

```
set spelllang=en_us,nl,medical
```

This line of code comes directly from the vim documentation.
It is findable under `:help spl`.  (`vim` version 8.1).

I restarted vim and I got a message that it was not installed.

To resolve this, I ran `:set spell` to interactively down the spelling files.
No luck on that:

```
:set spell
Cannot find spell file for "medical" in utf-8
Do you want me to try downloading it? Y

Downloading medical.utf-8.spl...
:!curl 'http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/medical.utf-8.spl' -L -o '/tmp/vYgP5zs/4.spl'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
"/tmp/vYgP5zs/4.spl" 9 lines, 314 character 
Could not find it, trying medical.ascii.spl...
:!curl 'http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/medical.ascii.spl' -L -o '/tmp/vYgP5zs/4.spl'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
"/tmp/vYgP5zs/4.spl" 9 lines, 314 character 
Sorry, downloading failed
Warning: Cannot find word list "medical.utf-8.spl" or "medical.ascii.spl"
```

So I tried searching the relevant ftp.vim.org link, and indeed there are not listed there.

What is an alternative route to installing these medical spelling files?

Comment: You may be able to download a plain-text version of an actual medical dictionary or spelling list and use vim + `:mkspell` to create the files.

Comment: This would be a very decent contribution if you want to create this spell file!!!

Comment: Thanks @alec and @ben! I used exactly your suggestions. It has been added down below such that others can benefit too.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The "medical" spell file does not exist, it is just an example of a name that is longer than two characters.  You would have to generate one yourself.

Comment: Thank you, Bram! I really appreciate that you made an account to help me out.
I cannot express how honored I feel to get an answer from the author of Vim himself. 
Thank you for your contributions to mankind!

Comment: @melvio You're probably the first one here on vi.se to get help from Bram :)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se], Bram! Glad to have you here.

Comment: Have you upvote the answer from our new contributor, the father of Vim.

Comment: Oh, no! Does this mean I'm going to have to actually know what I'm talking about when I post answers rather than just pretend? ;)  Welcome, Bram.

Comment: Hmm, how do we know he is Bram Moolenaar by the way?

Comment: Many moons ago I asked [Does Stack Exchange have a "Verified Account" feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58486) - I don't believe the policy has changed. Content is to be judged on its merits, not by what we (rightly or wrongly) believe about the poster.

Comment: _Content is to be judged on its merits, not by what we (rightly or wrongly) believe about the poster._ A standard with no chance of being met if the number of upvotes on this answer are any indication.

Comment: maybe Bram will answer it https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/_bQVXL12WCE

Comment: This is the real Bram. I send him this spell file question in an email in his native language. He replied, from his official email, that he answered on vi.se too. Moreover, this answer is essentially an exact translation from the answer in his email.

Answer (score 26):

In response to Bram's answer, I have found, modified, and compiled a medical spell file that can be used with Vim.

I've made the full instructions and the source code available under a GPL3 license [over here](https://github.com/melvio/medical-spell-files). However, I'll provide an abbreviated guide to installing the medical spell file here too.

##### How to install a medical spell file for vim

**Step 1**:
On a Linux machine, the medical spell file can be downloaded as follows:

```bash
curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/melvio/medical-spell-files/main/spell/medical.utf-8.spl" --output "${HOME}/.vim/spell/medical.utf-8.spl"
```

**Step 2**:
Add the medical dictionary to your `vimrc`. For example, by adding:

```
set spellang=en_us,medical
```

**Step 3**:
Start your happy Vimming. Is your spell checking disabled by default? You can enable it by running the following command in `vim`:

```
:set spell
```

---

Found any issues? Feel free to edit my post and/or send me a PR/issue [over here](https://github.com/melvio/medical-spell-files/issues).

---

Thanks again Bram Moolenaar for providing the correct answer.
And, thank you [@D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) for providing me with the solution:

> You may be able to download a plain-text version of an actual medical dictionary or spelling list and use vim +:mkspell to create the files.

Comment: Note: One can also add `Plug 'melvio/medical-spell-files'` in the right place if using Neovim.